# Celery schedule

Tags: django, celery

I have some schedule problem in Celery. 
The task works, however I want it to run once on Monday, but it runs every minute.
My schedule config:

```
    CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'kek': {
        'task': 'kek',
        'schedule': crontab(day_of_week=1),
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SO, @Sturm.

Just define hour and minute:

```
# Executes every Monday morning at 8:30 a.m.
crontab(hour=8, minute=30, day_of_week=1)#Monday is 1
```

This is happening because the default for crontab is to execute the task every minute.

For further information, just check the documentation for [crontab](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#crontab-schedules).